Are there any software packages to find the minimum number of constraints to fix a molecule structure?
I wanted to know if there are any modules or packages which help in identifying the bonds which should be fixed to make the molecule rigid. For example in $\ce{H2O}$ there are just three (trivial), $\ce{CH3OH}$ there are 10 and so on.

To answer your question more effectively, let's clarify what you mean by "should be fixed to make the molecule rigid." Are you looking to add additional bonds on top of the normal chemical bonds to achieve rigidity, or are you specifically interested in identifying the existing chemical bonding information for a given molecule?

What do you mean?

@Vasista The former actually. I wanted to know which atom-atom distances should be constrained so as to make the molecule completely rigid

@Atom in other words, you are trying to specify a molecular structure just using interatomic distances and not using any bond angles, right? So you are looking for a code/software that gives you the minimum number of these constraints (interatomic distances). But I am having problem understanding how you got the number 10 for $\ce{CH3OH}$. For $\ce{H2O}$, I am getting 3 (it's planar, so only H-H, and 2 O-H). But look at the 3D structure of methanol. I think the structure needs at least 12 interatomic distances!

The number of internal degrees of freedom, aka vibrations, is 3N-6, and you thus need 3N-6 constraints to keep the molecule rigid. If you want to do this with only pairwise atomic distances, perhaps try a sequential PCA analysis of the Wilson B-matrix in the space of all atom-pair distances, i.e. starting by the directly bonded (1-2) atom pairs, then add the non-redundant 1-3 pairs, then add the non-redundant 1-4 pairs, etc until you get 3N-6.

You can keep the molecule rigid using quaternions. If I remember well that comes from "Computer simulation of liquids", Allen and Tildesley.
